Get-AzureStorageBlob Powershell command gives error : SSL connection could not be established
I am trying to List and download the contents of An Azure Storage Account to my local server using Powershell,
I have PowerShell 7 with latest Azure modules installed
I have accessed the Storage account using a service principal
When I try to list the blob contents I'm Getting below error
"The SSL Connection Could not be established,See Inner Exception"
**Some Basic Information : **
I am new to Azure , My Vendor has some information in their Azure Storage Account , They have made to so , we cannot access this storage account via SAS Token and we can only access it via Private Endpoint set up in our own Azure RG
We have done the same , Now I'm trying to import the data into my local server , i have enabled my local server to be able to access the private end point i created
I have confirmed that there is no network issue between local server and the Private endpoint
My Vendor has also confirmed that there is no proxy from their end and the code has been tested to work
Please find my Method below :
    $saName = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    $clientId = "zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzz"
    $clientSecret = "sssss-sssss-sssss-ssssss"
    $tenantId = "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyy"
    $containerName = "container"

    **#I used below to By-Pass SSL Check **
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true};


    # Authenticate using Service Principal
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList        $clientId, $securePassword
    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenantId


    # Create a new storage context for the specific storage account
    $storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $saName -Endpoint "private-    endpoint.windows.net" -Protocol https -UseConnectedAccount


    **Everything work up until this point but when i use the below command i'm getting error**

    # Get the blobs
    Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $storageContext -Container $containerName

    Error : "The SSL Connection Could not be established,See Inner Exception" 


    **I have tried below to catch inner exception , but its no good , getting only same error again**

    try {
    # Code that may throw an SSL connection error
    Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $storageContext -Container $containerName
    }
    catch {
    # Catching the exception
    Write-Host "An error occurred: $($_.Exception.Message)"

    # Checking if there's an inner exception
    if ($_.Exception.InnerException) {
        Write-Host "Inner exception: $($_.Exception.InnerException.Message)"
    }
    }


SSL (obsolete and is really TLS) is performed before the HTTP request is sent to establish a secure (encrypted connection).  The error message may be misleading and is just an indication that the connection did not complete.  TLS failure is generally the cause but may not be the only reason for the connection to fail.  A credential issue is NOT the reason for the error.  A credential issue would give a http response with a failed status code.  You are not getting any response.  Common reasons for your error is the server not running, no route to the server, or TLS certificate error.

There's a couple of things you can check - (i) does nslookup <mystorageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net return the correct private ip address? (ii) does telnet <mystorageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net 443 connect? These will confirm whether there's network connectivity before you worry about certificates and / or authentication issues...

Hi mclayton , I have already tested the connectivity to .blob.core.windows.net . I used Test-NetConnection and it was successful
I have also had my Network team validate that packets are sent/received between the  local server and the Private Endpoint IP

Hi @AakashRavindran, Kindly create a context with the blob endpoint, assuming there are no restrictions from the network side
New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $saName -Endpoint "https://storageaccname.blob.core.windows.net/"

Hi Venkat , I have already done that and that part works , you can see the line in my code
Create a new storage context for the specific storage account
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $saName -Endpoint "private-    endpoint.windows.net" -Protocol https -UseConnectedAccount


Kindly share the $storageContext result screenshot by editing the QNS.

The SSL Connection Could not be established, See Inner Exception error may also occur if authentication fails. Refer to the same issue on Github."
You can use the script below to retrieve blob details using a private endpoint and it will catch any errors that occur during authentication and storage context.
$saName = "demotest12wd"
$caname = "venkat"
$appid = "fffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
$TenantID = "dddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
$appsecret = ConvertTo-SecureString "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($appid, $appsecret)

Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $TenantID -ServicePrincipal

# Bypass SSL certificate validation
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }

try {
  
      
       $sacontext = New-AzStorageContext -BlobEndpoint "https://demotest12wd.blob.core.windows.net/"

    try {
      
        $Blob = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $caname -Context$sacontext
        
       
        $Blob | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host "Blob Name: $($_.Name)"
        }

    } catch {
        Write-Host "An error occurred while accessing the blobs: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        
        if ($_.Exception.InnerException) {
            Write-Host "Inner exception: $($_.Exception.InnerException.Message)"
            
            # Recursive check for nested inner exceptions
            $ErrorinnerException = $_.Exception.InnerException
            while ($ErrorinnerException.InnerException) {
                $ErrorinnerException = $ErrorinnerException.InnerException
                Write-Host "Nested inner exception: $($ErrorinnerException.Message)"
            }
        }
    }

} catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred during authentication or storage context creation: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    
  
    if ($_.Exception.InnerException) {
        Write-Host "Inner exception: $($_.Exception.InnerException.Message)"
        
      
        $ErrorinnerException = $_.Exception.InnerException
        while ($ErrorinnerException.InnerException) {
            $ErrorinnerException = $ErrorinnerException.InnerException
            Write-Host "Nested inner exception: $($ErrorinnerException.Message)"
        }
    }
}

Output:

Storage account network configuration

Portal View

